# Vue.js в Laravel 5

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel5

Всем известно, что в laravel встроен vue.js. Но вот я не могу понять как там все устроено. Можете пожалуйста на пальцах объяснить, где хранить vue js объекты и как они взаимодействуют с php. Или можете скинуть ссылку где это подробно описано. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: laravel.com + vuejs.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Vue <strike>объекты</strike> компоненты** хранятся по пути `resources/assets/js/components`.
Так же хотелось бы напомнить что Laravel достаточно документированный фреймворк, поэтому большинство интересующей вас информации вы сможете найти в документации [ТУТ](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/),а конкретно по вашему текущему вопросу [ТУТ](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend#writing-vue-components)